# unix command for grand total

Tags: unix, command

Is there a easy way to calculate the grand total of all the numberic values specified line by line using a unix command (no script)

suppose

```
7612
7724
19844
20092
20184
20468
27100
36456
39428
54264
69008
97208
```

assume this is in a file

I want the total of all the values.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best one-liner I can come up with is

```
awk '{sum += $0} END {print sum}' file
```

Answer (score 6):

```
command | awk '{sum+=$1} END { print sum}'
```

Comment: the below is the correct answer, as i missed that requrement, to read it from a file. though i'd recommend useing $1 instead of $0, as $1 is the first field, $0 is the whole line.